# Poly-commitment based on Bulletproofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments, quantum-cryptography, data-privacy, zero-knowledge

I am reviewing the ZKP course, represented by the university of Berkley (https://zk-learning.org/). In pages 41 and 42 of lecture 6 that is attached below (https://zk-learning.org/assets/lecture6.pdf), the instructor explains the Poly-commitment based on Bulletproofs scheme. He uses an example for a polynomial with degree 3 and then define $f'_0 = rf_0 + f_2$ and $f'_1= rf_1 + f_3$. I think that if $d$ is bigger like 7, then we should define $'_0, f'_1, f'_2$, and $f'_3$. Am I right? If so, how we should determine the values for these new coefficients?

[image]